# Is this consindered safe redirect?

Tags: wp-redirect

Here is the code: (all pages are internal)

```
$URL = get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'page-slug') );
$subURL = get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'sub-slug') );

if( is_main_site() ) {  
    if ( is_page('about')){
        wp_safe_redirect($URL );
        exit();
    }
} else {    
    if (is_page('about')){
        wp_safe_redirect($subURL);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you consider safe? It highly depends on the definition of safe.

Comment: What I meant if there is anything fundamentally wrong with this code. I just want to make sure if this is right way to redirect from one page to another, where both page have same domain. ( I use it to redirect ppl who manually type a slug in URL, or delete child page slug in URL from CTP, but I need the to have page with same slug because of breadcrumbs and wp list pages. )